# Having trouble getting code to work together in different projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 project files.  One called Business and another that is my Website project in visual studio 2010.  I am trying to put a class called "AccountManager" inside the business project, and whenever something is done to the website it will go to the AccountManager and, for example, create an account using "CreateAccount(string, string, string)".  I am having trouble linking these together.  I keep getting errors saying

`constructors does not contain a constructor that takes '0' argument`

and also

`'Business.AccountManager' does not contain a definition for 'CreateAccount' and no extension method 'CreateAccount' accepting a first argument of type 'Business.AccountManager' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Im not exactly sure if im missing an import somewhere? or a reference?

Comment: How does your web project reference the business project? For a quick sanity check put the business.dll into the bin folder for the web project to check it's not the code. If that works then your web project is missing the business project reference and there are a bunch of build settings that can put a reference or the dll in the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are marking your constructor as public and your methods as public...